# How to do regular database cleanup in a JPA application?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jpa, consolidation

Short background:
I have a software that regularly downloads files. The Statistics of these downloads are stored in the database as a DownloadResult entity, which is in turn associated to the entity representing the download job.

Now I want to make sure, that only a fixed number of the n latest downloads are preserved in the database. AFAIK in a classical (non ORM/JPA) database application, this would be done with a stored procedure.

What would be the right way to do this in a JPA driven application?

Comment: What's about giving these downloads a sequence number and drop the once which are current_no < n?

Comment: Simple and smart! However I was not wondering about the exact criterium (be it a sequence number or based on timestamps) but I was wondering about how to run it. It reads like: I don't know much about stored procedures and I am currently not very eager to learn it, if it can be done "the java way" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Quartz http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ if you want to stay withing Java boundaries, if it is not a requirement you can go with stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look into it. I'm already using java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService. Any reasons why I should prefer Quartz over classes from standard API?

Comment: Couple of them: you don't need to run scheduler.schedule(), just setup your schedule, and Quartz has much more powerful way for setting up schedules, for instance you can set it up to sun every Saturday night. Also it is more convenient you can set up to sun your session bean's method directly from the scheduler

Comment: My understanding of Quartz is that it works how it would be specified in EJB spec

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "how it would be specified in EJB spec". Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is Java SE specific, not even sure it is allowed to be used in EE, in Java EE 5 spec they don't have advanced declaration-based scheduler.